# jQuery quiz application how to implement a point based answering system?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I am reasonably new to javascript and jquery. I have been looking at tutorials which have been a good starting point however they all seem to have one question that is right, so they are able to check within a function if the users answer is correct via a if equal to statement for example.

```
if (answers[i] == userAnswers[i]) { 
        flag = true; 
    }
```

What I would like to do however, is have a different value attached to each of the potential answers for example

```
var 1 = 50
var 2 = 0
var 3 = 10
```

Question 1

```
var a = 1
var b = 2
var c = 3
var d = 3
```

Question 2

```
var a = 3
var b = 1
var c = 2
var d = 3
```

What would be the best way to do something like this?

Comment: How can an answer be "okay"?

Comment: How would you implement this? Would every question always have 'a' as the 'good' answer?

Comment: I just used these names as an example I have updated them to numbers now.

Comment: @Hawkeye No, this would change depending on the question I have updated my question which may help you understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, an assumption:

- `answers[i]` contains a **number** which is what the user picked as an answer to question `i` (Note: if `answers[i]` is in fact a character, you can get the integer value by subtracting `answers[i]` by the ascii value of 'a').

To do what you want to do, simply define a 2-dimensional array `score[i][j]`, where `i` is the index of the question, and `j` is the option number (ie the asnwer to question `i`), then `score[i][j]` gives the score for this question. So let's say for question 1, the options are as you described above (ie a = good, b = wrong, ...), then you would have

```
//set the values for the answers
score[1][1] = good; score[1][2] = wrong; score[1][3] =  wrong; score[1][4] = okay
score[2][1] = okay; score[2][2] = good; score[2][3] = wrong;
//more score setting

//get the value of the answer
var score_q1 = score[1][answers[1]]
var score_q2 = score[2][answers[2]]
```

ie, since `answers[i]` contains the value of the answer as a number, by calling `score[question_nb][answers[question_nb]]` you get the score for that question. In this case, there are no if statements. If you want to get the total score, just loop over all questions and sum up the score for that question.

Comment: That makes perfect sense thanks for your help

Comment: Just testing the solution now and getting a `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '1' of undefined"` on the 2-dimensional array. Before the `//set the values of the answers` section would I have to initialize the array or should I create it as `var score = [[0,1], [0,2]]`etc ?

Comment: Did you try declaring the array first?

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be a key/value pair. I would try something like json. You would have your json with a key of good and a value (for points) as 50. The json would look something like below:

```
var kvPair = {"good":"50", "wrong":"0", "okay":"10"};
```

then when someone clicks an answer it would run ajax to determine the score:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "someUrl",
    data: kvPair,
    success: function (data) {
        //do something with score data
    },
    error: function (event) {
        ShowErrorLabel("ERROR in ajax call('someUrl'): \n" + "Error : " + event.status + " - " + event.statusText);
    }
});
```