# How correctly initialize a 2-dimensional array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Following a suggestion made on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36408610/jquery-quiz-application-how-to-implement-a-point-based-answering-system/36408817#36408817) question I am attempting to create a two-dimensional array, however I am currently running into a error on running I believe this is because the formatting is incorrect or I am missing some prior initialization.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '1' of undefined
```

Here is a sample of what my code currently looks like:

```
var answers = [];
answers [0] = [];
answers[0][1] = accept; answers[0][2] = wrong; answers[0][3] = wrong; 
answers[1][1] = wrong; answers[1][2] = best; answers[1][3] = wrong;
```

Answer (score 4):

You are missing initialization, you never initializated `array[1]`.

Here's a version of your code with this fix:

```
var answers = [];
answers[0] = [];
answers[1] = [];
answers[0][1] = accept;
answers[0][2] = wrong;
answers[0][3] = wrong; 
answers[1][1] = wrong;
answers[1][2] = best;
answers[1][3] = wrong;
```

Comment: This, and Strings need to be wrapped with quotes (Not causing this specific error, though)

Comment: Could you give me an example please?

Comment: According to a comment on the other answer, `accept`, `wrong`, and `best` are variables, not strings.

Comment: @Barmar, you are right, it's fixed now

Answer (score 2):

If you're hardcoding the elements like that, you can do this:

```
var answers = [
    [accept, wrong, wrong],
    [wrong, best, wrong]
];
```

Assuming `accept`, `wrong` and `best` are vars.

Comment: Yes accept, wrong and best are vars - Using this solution would I  be able to call array elements like this - i=index y=option_index , answers[i][y] and get the value attached  to each such as accept?

Comment: @NicolaSansom Yes. This will define `answers[0][0]`, `answers[0][1]`, `answers[0][2]`, `answers[1][0]`, `answers[1][1]` and `answers[1][2]`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to bother if the array was initialized or not, you can initialize it if it is not defined, like this:

```
function insert(array,path,value) {
  path.forEach(function(i,pos) {
    if(array[i]===undefined) array[i] = [];
    if(pos<path.length-1) array = array[i];
    else array[i] = value;
  });
}

var answers = [];
insert(answers,[1,2,3],"accept");
alert(answers[1][2][3]); // accept
```

Comment: I use a similar function in PHP. This is quite handy.